# declare function properties inside

Tags: javascript, function, properties, scope

I know that we can set a function property as below

```
function f(){}
f['a']=1;//setting function property from outside
alert(f.a)//alert 1
```

But is it possible to set a property of function as below or is there any other similar way of declaring properties inside a function,rather than from outside?

```
function f() {
a: 1
}

alert(f.a);  //get 1 as output
```

**EDIT:**
Looking for some way which does not use any object creation from the function constructor or use prototypes

Comment: yes that is wat i mean

Comment: yes, you can certainly assign properties to a function object from within the function. in all functions, `arguments.callee` refers to the enclosing function, but you really should name your functions that use such interaction as callee is deprecated.

Comment: @dandavis: *"in all functions, arguments.callee"* Not all, `callee` doesn't exist in strict mode ( and really it should never have existed in the first place). As you said, use a name, then use the name within the function (if that's what's desired): `function f() { f.a = 1; }`. But I'm sure the OP didn't want to have it get defined only when called (and repeatedly redefined on every call).

Comment: from what I know arguments.callee is used for recursive calls to anonymous functions

Comment: @Flake: Only if you have a *really good reason* for needing those to be anonymous (since the demise, largely, of IE8, I can't think of one, as [this bug](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html) is no longer an excuse). And not in strict mode, since `callee` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is not. Inside the function goes only the body, i.e. the code that is executed when the function is called. A function literal / declaration is not an object literal, even if both use curly braces.

If you're looking for a more declarative way than assignment to put static properties on a function, use some kind of `extend` functionality:

```
var f = Object.assign(function f() {}, {
    a: 1
});
```

(all of [`_.extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend), [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/), [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) will work for this purpose - otherwise just use [`f.a =`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators))

Comment: so the only way to set a property is from outside?

Comment: @Flake: You can do it from inside (`f.a = 1`), but it will only take effect the first time you call the function, which I'm guessing isn't what you want...

Comment: @Flake: Well, you can set the property from the inside as well, but then you'd have to call the function to execute the assignment. Not what you want I guess.

Comment: and if I do it from outside,then where does it go?

Comment: a function is just an object. code that runs can adjust it. that code can be in or out of the function itself.

Comment: @Flake: On the outside, the assignment just goes after the function definition, like in your first snippet.

Comment: @Bergi: Or before, as long as it's a declaration. ;-) (**Sometimes** it can be not actually horrible style...)

Comment: its just that everywhere it says that function is an object,so I thought why not set a property inside function

Comment: @Flake: Functions are objects, but function declarations are not object declarations. Different semantics. Similarly, you can't assign an `a` property to an array with an array declaration, either, even though arrays are objects. `Object.assign` and such is the closest you'll get to doing this declaratively.

Comment: Be aware that as of July 2015, `Object.assign` is not widely implemented in mainstream browsers. It is part of the forthcoming ECMAScript 2015 standard, previously known as ES6.

Comment: just to be clear: it's not 100% clear that the reason you guys are saying it cannot be done internally refers to assigning it without invoking the function. if invoking the function is ok (not shown in OP), then internal assignment is fine and intuitive.

Comment: @dandavis: :-) See my first comment above.

Comment: @KieranPotts: Yeah, that's why I linked the docs. However it can be trivially shimmed, so I'm not reluctant using it :-)

Answer (score -1):

The only way this can be done is if the function is invoked with the `new` keyword:

```
var f = function() {
    this.a = 4;
}
var test = new f();
alert(test.a); // 4
```

I've published some more tests on this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/j4svr90x/2/

Comment: That doesn't set a property on the function at all. *(Not my dv, though I did reach for it and then decide not.)*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is absolutely right. Strictly speaking, this sets a property on the object that is instantiated from the function call.