# Declare function with property in one statement?

Tags: javascript

I know that I can create a function:

```
const fn = () => {}
```

And I know that I can attach a property to it:

```
fn.a = 'a'
```

Can I use some kind of object literal syntax to do what I did above in one statement?

I'm thinking something along the lines of:

```
const fn = {
  (): {},
  a: 'a'
}
```

Comment: I believe this article will help you out [Proper use of const for defining functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33040703/proper-use-of-const-for-defining-functions)

Comment: Take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20734003/16688813

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/31412639/1048572

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it in one statement like this.

`const fn = Object.assign(() => {}, { a: 'a' });`

Answer (score 1):

How about we make a little utility function to accomplish that?

```js
function createFunc(func, props) {
  Object.keys(props).forEach((key) => (func[key] = props[key]));
  return func;
}

const f = createFunc(() => console.log("hello"), { a: "A", b: "B" });

f();
console.log(f.a);
console.log(f.b);
```